# Convert a stream of JSONs to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, file-conversion

I want to convert a stream of JSONs (nearly 10,000) pasted in a file to a CSV file with a particular format for headers and values.

I have the following streams of JSON data :

```
{"shortUrlClicks":"594","longUrlClicks":"594","countries":[{"count":"125","id":"IQ"},{"count":"94","id":"US"},{"count":"56","id":"TR"},{"count":"50","id":"SA"},{"count":"29","id":"DE"},{"count":"24","id":"TN"},{"count":"20","id":"DZ"},{"count":"14","id":"EG"},{"count":"13","id":"MA"},{"count":"12","id":"PS"}],"browsers":[{"count":"350","id":"Chrome"},{"count":"100","id":"Firefox"},{"count":"46","id":"Safari"},{"count":"35","id":"Mobile"},{"count":"20","id":"Mobile Safari"},{"count":"20","id":"SamsungBrowser"},{"count":"8","id":"MSIE"},{"count":"6","id":"Opera"},{"count":"3","id":"OS;FBSV"},{"count":"2","id":"Maxthon"}],"platforms":[{"count":"227","id":"Android"},{"count":"221","id":"Windows"},{"count":"67","id":"iPhone"},{"count":"30","id":"X11"},{"count":"25","id":"Macintosh"},{"count":"8","id":"iPad"},{"count":"2","id":"Android 4.2.2"},{"count":"1","id":"Android 4.1.2"},{"count":"1","id":"Android 4.3"},{"count":"1","id":"Android 5.0.1"}],"referrers":[{"count":"340","id":"unknown"},{"count":"193","id":"t.co"},{"count":"38","id":"m.facebook.com"},{"count":"12","id":"addpost.it"},{"count":"4","id":"plus.google.com"},{"count":"3","id":"www.facebook.com"},{"count":"1","id":"goo.gl"},{"count":"1","id":"l.facebook.com"},{"count":"1","id":"lm.facebook.com"},{"count":"1","id":"plus.url.google.com"}]}
{"shortUrlClicks":"594","longUrlClicks":"594","countries":[{"count":"125","id":"IQ"},{"count":"94","id":"US"},{"count":"56","id":"TR"},{"count":"50","id":"SA"},{"count":"29","id":"DE"},{"count":"24","id":"TN"},{"count":"20","id":"DZ"},{"count":"14","id":"EG"},{"count":"13","id":"MA"},{"count":"12","id":"PS"}],"browsers":[{"count":"350","id":"Chrome"},{"count":"100","id":"Firefox"},{"count":"46","id":"Safari"},{"count":"35","id":"Mobile"},{"count":"20","id":"Mobile Safari"},{"count":"20","id":"SamsungBrowser"},{"count":"8","id":"MSIE"},{"count":"6","id":"Opera"},{"count":"3","id":"OS;FBSV"},{"count":"2","id":"Maxthon"}],"platforms":[{"count":"227","id":"Android"},{"count":"221","id":"Windows"},{"count":"67","id":"iPhone"},{"count":"30","id":"X11"},{"count":"25","id":"Macintosh"},{"count":"8","id":"iPad"},{"count":"2","id":"Android 4.2.2"},{"count":"1","id":"Android 4.1.2"},{"count":"1","id":"Android 4.3"},{"count":"1","id":"Android 5.0.1"}],"referrers":[{"count":"340","id":"unknown"},{"count":"193","id":"t.co"},{"count":"38","id":"m.facebook.com"},{"count":"12","id":"addpost.it"},{"count":"4","id":"plus.google.com"},{"count":"3","id":"www.facebook.com"},{"count":"1","id":"goo.gl"},{"count":"1","id":"l.facebook.com"},{"count":"1","id":"lm.facebook.com"},{"count":"1","id":"plus.url.google.com"}]}
```

... and so on.

I want to convert it into this form in CSV with whatever the headers (shortUrlclicks, longUrclicks, etc.) are:

[image: OUTPUT]

I would be thankful to if you could please help me in the same. Any code in python or any other language would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library from the Python Standard Library to read the JSON and read/write files using the [OS](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) Library (from Python Standard Library too).

It would be something like this:

```
f = File.open('file.json', 'r')
items = json.loads(f.read())
csv_file = ""

for row in items():
    new_row = ""
    # get columns somehow
    for column in columns:
        new_row = "%s," % column 

    # Finished row, append a '\n' char to the row string.
    csv_file.append("%s\n" % new_row)

# write json file
out = File.open('out.csv', 'rw')
out.write(csv_file)
out.close()
```

PS: I didn't run this code before posting. This is something to you to get an idea.

Comment: OP aksed to create a CSV file out of 'Streaming' JSONs not a file JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pandas to do this for you.

## read your JSON file like this

> > df = pandas.read_json('filename.json')

## write to csv

> > df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False) # set index false if u don't need it

**Example:**
http://hayd.github.io/2013/pandas-json

**REF:**
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: OP aksed to create a CSV file out of 'Streaming' JSONs not a file JSON.